# Is it possible to configure LXD in local juju setup to use ZFS on file backed?

Tags: juju, zfs, lxd

I want to setup juju openstack cloud in LXD containers on my local KVM machines (manually created).
By default Juju creates LXD provider as a directory.
But from LXD documentation I see that it's better to use ZFS for LXD.
How I can tell to juju (latest version) to create lxd provider with zfs on file?

I can init lxd manually with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y zfsutils-linux
lxd init --auto --storage-backend=zfs --storage-create-loop=40
```

and I can start LXD container manually (with lxc launch)
but juju doesn't want to use such deployed lxd and doesn't start containers there.

Answer (score 0):

answer in /var/log/juju/machine-0.log

2021-03-22 19:52:58 ERROR juju.container-setup container_initialisation.go:118 starting container provisioner for lxd: setting up container dependencies on host machine: juju does not support IPv6. Disable IPv6 in LXD via:
lxc network set lxdbr0 ipv6.address none
and run the command again

after this command juju can run lxc containers.